# SQL Server Express 2017 SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Recently I installed SQL Server Express 2017 to use it in a android project which I am currently programming in C#.

After I installed it I wanted to connect to it in my Application but everytime I try this I get the following error: Server does not exist or access denied.

I can connect to the server via Server Management Studio or Visual Studio, but not from my Application.

I found the following instructions to solve this problem:

1. Check if Server is running
2. Checked connection string
3. Remote Connection on SQL Server is enabled
4. Port 1433 is opened in my Firewall

I found these solutions to this problem on this Site:
http://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/database-does-not-exist-access-denied/

But everything I tried failed. I try to login to my SQLServer Express Instance with Windows authentification.

This is my current connectionstring and my code to test if I can connect to my Database:

```
        public SqlController()
        {
        connectionString = @"Data Source=NICKLAS-DESKTOP\NIWDEV;Initial Catalog=NCProzessPlanerDEMO;Integrated Security=True";
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

    public bool TestConnectionToDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlConnection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

To test my code i call the method TestConnectionToDatabase() which ends up in catching the exception.

I don't know what to try else, thanks for every help in Advance :)

Comment: What type of application is it? Are you running it in an emulator? Perhaps the emulator config doesn't allow access to the machine/network?

Comment: You're using a server with an instance name remotely. That additionally requires that the SQL Server Browser service is running and its port (1434) is open for UDP traffic. Alternatively, if that instance is the only instance running, simply omit it and the connection will be made with the instance listening on port 1433, whatever its name.

Comment: You are running the application on the same machine where the data server exists? or it running on different machine if so than do this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx

Comment: Are you sure the android machine can resolve NICKLAS-DESKTOP to an IP?

Comment: It's an C# Application which runs in Visual Studio. I have to connect my Phone to debug the application, so I think the application is running on my Phone. I didn't thought about this, but is it possible that I can't reach the server because the code is executed on my Phone? 
@SaurabhChauhan I will try your solution :)

Comment: @BugFinder No actually I didn't thought about this at all. Is SaurabhChauhans mentioned link the solution to my problem?

Comment: express by default is for you on your pc - it can be opened but it seems as you say you havent thought this through.  You need to configure express to accept tcp connections, you need to make sure its listening and allowing all traffic, you will need to be sure that the android user will have authority to access it, and can see it..  depending on how your android machine works if its a phone for example its outside your network unless on wifi

Comment: Okay thanks, so now I now whats the problem. I will try to configure express in the next days. Actually I thought I can use the Express Server only for testing my application. Maybe there is an easier way to store data from the android application. 
Thanks for alls comments and every help :) 
Can I close the question somewhere now?

Comment: You can probably flag it to be closed but android doesnt now windows authentication, youd do better to set up a static sql user

Comment: Okay good to now! Sure, I will look if I have time to test this at the weekend. At the moment I am not completly sure how I will save and store data in my application. I think that using Sql Server Express isn't the best option to store data if more users use the application. 
As I mentioned this was only thought to be used as a testing server. 
Thanks for every help and tips :)